# Networking a server with wireless network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, bridge

Right, I have a wireless network at home, and a server without a wireless adaptor, I also have upteen amounts of ethernet cables lying around. There is a laptop in the same room as the server, with a wireless connection, would there be a way to connect the server to the internet using the laptop?

Comment: The answer is yes, but your question is just a bit broad.

Answer (score 0):

You could just connect the server to the wireless router directly with your cable.

Otherwise, you're going to need to be a lot more specific about the type of server, laptop, and network.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect the server to the laptop with a crossover cable. Depending on what operating system the machines are running, there are different methods you can use to connect to the internet through the laptop. On Windows, there is [**Internet Connection Sharing (ICS)**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Connection_Sharing) for example.

Comment: A lot of modern computers have auto-crossover ports. Try a straight cable before trying to track-down/make a crossover cable.